# C# process output redirect from a bat file that runs other commands

Tags: c#

I am trying to redirect the output from the following BAT file:

```
@echo Parando proceso matrix (%1)...
@plink pi@%1 -pw raspberry sudo killall -9 matrix
```

Using the following code in C#

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("run.bat", "192.168.1.100);
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.OutputDataReceived += ProcessOutput;
process.StartInfo = psi;
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();


private void ProcessOutput(Object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
    {
        ProcessOut.Invoke(new ThreadStart(delegate ()
        {
            ProcessOut.Text += e.Data + "\r\n";
        }));
    }
}
```

But I only get the "echo" output, not the "plink" output, which is a command line program that connects to a SSH server running a command and showing its output. This "plink" command is being executed.

If I run the bat file directly the output is right.

Comment: Not answering since this is a wild guess, but either try `RedirectStandardInput = true` on your process, or pass `-batch` to `plink` on your batch file so it doesn't need an stdin. I recall weird things happened with plink once I had to use it. Also try redirecting the stderr (`RedirectStandardError = true`) to see if it's writing there instead of stdout

Comment: I've tried to look for some old code where I fought against all of this and could eventually solve it, but can't really remember how), but haven't been able to find it :-/

Comment: You wait for process to exit right? With WaitForExit, since it is not included in your code.